# Убрать кнопку Пробки на Яндекс карте JS

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Каким образом можно убрать эту кнопку? Я нашел в документации код, но как его написать правильно непонятно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {...
```

Как дальше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
     center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
     zoom: 9,
     // Сюда вписываете через запятую какие элементы управления нужны на карте
     controls: ['trafficControl', '', '']
},
```

> [Список основных элементов управления](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.storage-docpage/#control.storage)
>
> [Песочница](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/)